# Ktor | How to connect FreeMaker-Templates with any kind of File?

Tags: html, css, kotlin, freemarker, ktor

**Hello everyone,**

I just started learing Kotlin and Ktor for Web Development.
I started creating a Template and everything worked perfectly but now I want to add style to my Templates. In the Kotlin Docs they add style with HTML but I would like to add style with a CSS-File or add a favicon to my head section.
Is that possible?

NK

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FreeMarker templates for any kind of text content, just make sure that your server responds with an appropriate content type. Here is an example:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    install(FreeMarker) {
        templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(this::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
    }
    routing {
        get("/style.css") {
            call.respond(
                FreeMarkerContent(
                    "style.css",
                    mapOf("mainColor" to "#aabbcc"),
                    contentType = ContentType.Text.CSS
                )
            )
        }

        get("/") {
            call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.html", mapOf<Unit, Unit>()))
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

templates/style.css

```
body {
    background-color: ${mainColor}
}
```

templates/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But there is another problem. 
How can I connect Images to my html file. 
Everytime I tryed i get this error:

/img/logo.png. Exception class freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "img/logo.png" in line 114, column 255